# Why am I getting Promise { Pending }?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm working on a web scraper in Javascript using puppeteer and whenever I try to log the text content of an element it says "Promise { Pending }". I've looked at other answers and none of them worked

```
const element = await page.$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_NameLinkButton");

const text = await page.evaluate(element => element.textContent, element);

console.log(text);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is correct. but I think you forget to add `await` before `page.evaluate()`.

---

There three ways to do that.

- First way. just like what are you do. but I don't prefer it because
  you don't need to call `page.evaluate()` to get `.textContent`

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

puppeteer.launch().then(async browser => {
    const elementId = 'container';

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://metwally.me');

    const element = await page.$(`#${elementId}`);

    if (element) {
        const text = await page.evaluate(element => element.textContent, element);
        console.log(text);
    } else {
        // handle not exists id
        console.log('Not Found');
    }
});
```

---

- Second way. you will call `page.evaluate()` and use JavaScript Dom to get `textContent`. like `document.getElementById(elementId).textContent`.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

puppeteer.launch().then(async browser => {
    const elementId = 'container';

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://metwally.me');

    const text = await page.evaluate(
        elementId => {
            const element = document.getElementById(elementId);
            return element ? element.textContent : null;
        }, elementId);

    if (text !== null) {
        console.log(text);
    } else {
        // handle not exists id
        console.log('Not Found');
    }
});
```

---

- Third way. you will select element by puppeteer selector then get `textContent` property using `await element.getProperty('textContent')` then get value from `textContent._remoteObject.value`.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

puppeteer.launch().then(async browser => {
    const elementId = 'container';

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://metwally.me');

    const element = await page.$(`#${elementId}`);

    if (element) {
        const textContent = await element.getProperty('textContent');
        const text = textContent._remoteObject.value;
        console.log(text);
    } else {
        // handle not exists id
        console.log('Not Found');
    }
});
```

---

> NOTE: All these examples working successfully in my machine.

```
os ubuntu 20.04
nodejs v10.19.0
puppeteer v1.19.0
```

---

References

- [Puppeteer page.$](https://devdocs.io/puppeteer/index#pageselector)
- [Document.getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)
- [Node.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I'll accept it as the answer once I can